# How to monitor and protect machine

Tags: ssh, xubuntu, monitor, fail2ban

Recently I've been locked out of my Ubuntu as a precaution and was notified that my vps/dedi was used for DDoS attacks on other services within the host as well as outside the host.
I've been granted private access limited to my IP to "fix" the issue

I've changed my password as well installed fail2ban, I know it is not much (but is honest work) and now I am looking for a way I can limit or monitor the outgoing usage or at least limit it on the suspicious events.

The main issue I am facing is that I don't know if someone logged in as root or accessed some services which are public (mostly used pterodactyl, but also have some additional services installed)

Any additional advice is always welcome.

Comment: There is no info here to understand the issue or to offer any help. What version of Ubuntu? What do you mean by locked out? Notified by whom? There is nothing here that would help know if the the machine was used or how it was done.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information provided the version is ubuntu 20.04, locked out mean that machine is not accessible and in other words it is "suspended" i was provided access with my ip to implement changes so it can be permanently unlocked. Notified by the dedicated machine host
If there is any further information needed i can provide it within the next reply